# Как использовать Lumen framework без роутера?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

собираюсь писать плагин для Wordpress хочу для своей работы использовать фреймворк Lumen, но как правильно его использовать в обход классического использования роутера и роутов в файлике route.php ? Смысл в  том что в Wordpress все ajax запросы поступают на один роут wp-admin.php и там уже в зависимости от параметров обрабатываются данные в колбеках. Теперь вот как на базе вп использовать люмен, чтобы не отвалились мидлверы и контроллеры?

Comment: Как зарегистрировать поступивший реквест в системе, чтобы он прошел через мидлвер и чтобы был доступен в контролере в классическом виде? Я конечно могу и без этого обойтись но с этим было бы приятнее.

Comment: Или же может как-то передать сам роут и реквест в файлик route.php, чтобы сымитировать реальный запрос

Comment: Вы можете в wp использовать и свой ajax запрос. Указать свой обработчик, не admin-ajax.php, и выполнять свой php код

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на данный момент решил проблему, фреймворк крутой и легко подстроился под wp, пришлось внедрить пару моментов в ядро и все заработало :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак проблемку решил, кому интересно объясню. 
Для начала определимся с точкой входа аякс запросов

```
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    $app = require __DIR__.'/core/bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->run();
    wp_die();
}
```

В колбеке запускаем приложение.
Далее в методе `dispath` файла `/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php` 
для переменной `$pathInfo` нужно указать наш `uri`
Конечно ядро править такое себе занятие, но я не стал заморачиваться, да и это не  стандартное решение как бы, просто нужно избежать обновлений этого файла в будущем.

Чтобы использовать Eloquent ORM нужно в файлике `bootstrap/app.php` расскоментить две строчки

```
 $app->withFacades();
 $app->withEloquent();
```

И теперь например, чтобы обратиться к таблице вп пользователей нужно в моделе `User.php` добавить строчку     `protected $table = 'wp_users';` где `wp_users` название таблицы в бд (стоит учесть динамочность префикса). После этого в контроллере можем юзать наш орм `User::where('ID', 1)->first();`